# MongoDB c# driver SetWrapped issue

Tags: c#, mongodb

** Updated with more code:

I have a class/entity similar to

```
public class price
    {
        public decimal mrp { get; set; }

}
```

This is part of a complex doc like following:

```
{
  "Name" : "Name",
  "_id" : ObjectId("522a83c2a833e20db4b028ea"),

  "price" : {
    "mrp" : 599,
  }
}
```

I am using c# driver to update this doc ... like the following:

// function to check if a field exists in the doc
private bool check_field(BsonDocument doc, string field_name)
        {
            if (doc.Contains(field_name))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

// get the whole doc

```
foreach (var c in cursor)
            {
                product prd = new product();
                prd.id = check_field(c.ToBsonDocument(), "id") ? convertToString(c.ToBsonDocument()["id"]) : null;
                prd.price = check_field(c.ToBsonDocument(), "price") ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<price>(c.ToBsonDocument()["price"].ToString()) : null;
                products.Add(prd);
            } 

for (var i = 0; i < products.Count(); i++)
            {
                price price_list = new price();
    price_list.mrp = 500;
    MongoDB.Driver.Builders.UpdateBuilder update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.SetWrapped("price", (price)price_list);
            }
```

When I execute the command, I expect $set command to be issued as

```
{ "$set" : { "price" : { "mrp" : 500 }}}
but get this instead
{ "$set" : { "price" : { "mrp" : "599" }}}
```

Any help / pointer would be really helpful

Comment: Would need to see more code. What you've posted just wouldn't happen without there being some other interactions that you haven't included in your question's details.

Comment: (Like does your code fetch the original document into the `price` object before the update occurs?)

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked well when I changed the data type to double (or float). Decimal is 64 bit - so mongo stores it as NumberLong.